# Change md5 signature of image file in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

so I want to write A little python script to change the md5 signature of an image,

```
hasher = hashlib.md5()
with open('Images\Test.jpg', 'rb') as afile:
    buf = afile.read()
    print("test")
    hasher.update(buf)
print(hasher.hexdigest())
```

This will get the photo md5 but I need a way to change it, Any ideas?

Comment: A MD5 (or other) hash is a function of *every single byte of data*.  The only way to change it is to change the data.  You can certainly modify or append bytes in your image file, but this is likely to corrupt the image.

Comment: @jasonharper    If i wanted to add a null byte, how would I do so?

Comment: Open the file in `'ab'` mode to append, do `.write(b'\0')`.  No guarantees that everything will still see the file as valid.

Comment: Maybe just add or change some metadata using [exif](https://pypi.org/project/exif/) then recompute the md5.